# Keyboard shortcuts in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Lab (latest version, I think: 0.34.12) on an up-to-date Mac notebook (with a remote server), and none of the commands to display keyboard shortcuts are working (Command-Shift-P or Ctl-Shift-P, or H while in "command mode").

Also Keyboard Shortcuts is not on the help menu, though sites such as [this one](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/) suggest that it should be.  Is anyone having similar problems, or know what might be wrong?  Jupyter Lab is functioning fine in all other respects, as far as I can tell.